# Grafana InfluxDB average over time

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have inherited a Grafana dashboard using InfluxDB. Data is written to the database only some of the time, for example, maybe for 3 hours and then stop for 1 hour. I would like to set up a panel that displays the percentage 'uptime' for a given time range, so in this case it would dispaly 75%. I have tried the 'avg_over_time()' function but it seems this function is undefined: "InfluxDB Error: undefined function avg_over_time()".

Is there a simple way to set this up, or how might I access this 'avg_over_time()' function?

Comment: `avg_over_time` is function of Prometheus and not InfluxDB.

Comment: Could [this thread](https://community.influxdata.com/t/trying-to-get-an-average-over-n-days-and-i-must-be-doing-it-wrong/5991) help?